# Multiple-line labels align horizontally in OS

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have an issue while making a cell with 2 multiple line UILabels in left side and 1 multiple line UILabel in right side. I want to show all text of the right UILabel, and 2 left UILabels take the rest space.
I set Content Compression Resistance Priority and Content Hugging Priority of the right UILabel to 1000, but 2 left UILabel collapsed (in this [video](https://streamable.com/lq5ns4))

How can I achieve this?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: how about if you set the width of right label `less than or equal to 0.5 * width of the cell` ?

Comment: @nghiahoang i tried but nothing changes

Comment: @MyWill - edit your question and try to clarify what you want. Looking at the video, it's not clear which labels are which.